# C++ undefined reference to some of defined functions in linked library of CMake project

Tags: c++, kubernetes, cmake

I'm trying to use the kubernetes c client api library[[https://github.com/kubernetes-client/c/]](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/c/).
I just created a CMake C++ project. The project contain only `CMakeLists.txt` and `main.cpp` files. I have followed the instructions to install the client library and `libkubernetes.so` is found on `/usr/local/lib`

Following is my code.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(k8s)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(k8s main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(k8s PRIVATE /usr/local/lib/libkubernetes.so)
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <kubernetes/include/apiClient.h>
#include <kubernetes/config/kube_config.h>
#include <kubernetes/api/CoreV1API.h>

int main() {
    char *basePath = NULL;
    sslConfig_t *sslConfig = NULL;
    list_t *apiKeys = NULL;
    int rc = load_kube_config(&basePath, &sslConfig, &apiKeys, NULL);/* NULL means loading configuration from $HOME/.kube/config */
    if (rc != 0) {
        printf("Cannot load kubernetes configuration.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // commented below for [check 1]
    apiClient_t *apiClient = apiClient_create_with_base_path(basePath, sslConfig, apiKeys);
    if (!apiClient) {
        printf("Cannot create a kubernetes client.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    v1_pod_list_t *pod_list = NULL;
    pod_list = CoreV1API_listNamespacedPod(apiClient,
                                           "default",    /*namespace */
                                           NULL,    /* pretty */
                                           NULL,    /* allowWatchBookmarks */
                                           NULL,    /* continue */
                                           NULL,    /* fieldSelector */
                                           NULL,    /* labelSelector */
                                           NULL,    /* limit */
                                           NULL,    /* resourceVersion */
                                           NULL,    /* resourceVersionMatch */
                                           NULL,    /* sendInitialEvents */
                                           NULL,    /* timeoutSeconds */
                                           NULL     /* watch */
    );
    printf("return code=%ld\n", apiClient->response_code);

    apiClient_free(apiClient);
    apiClient = NULL;
    free_client_config(basePath, sslConfig, apiKeys);
    basePath = NULL;
    sslConfig = NULL;
    apiKeys = NULL;
    apiClient_unsetupGlobalEnv();
}
```

When I build and compiled with `cmake .` and `make` I got following error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/k8s.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `apiClient_create_with_base_path(char const*, sslConfig_t*, list_t*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `CoreV1API_listNamespacedPod(apiClient_t*, char*, char*, int*, char*, char*, char*, int*, char*, char*, int*, int*, int*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x11b): undefined reference to `apiClient_free(apiClient_t*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x157): undefined reference to `apiClient_unsetupGlobalEnv()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/k8s.dir/build.make:98: k8s] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/k8s.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

[check 1] Since the error is not reported for `load_kube_config` I just check commenting the shown part.
Then, when I built the project with `cmake .` and `make` got following error.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libyaml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But, I managed to get it fixed by exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`. The the code part with `load_kube_config` works.
Then, I uncommented code part I commented before executed. I still get the same error.

I just wondering If I linked `libkubernetes.so` and all of those api interface files are coming from that library why some of the functions do work and some don't.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: `load_kube_config` is a function that comes from `<kubernetes/config/kube_config.h>` file. Which is coming from the library `libkubernetes.so`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They seem don't care of C++ and including their header files into .cpp files. Since your code is the plain C if you remove `#include <iostream>`, rename your file main.cpp to main.c. Or include their files forcing C linkages for their API functions:

```
extern "C" {
#include <kubernetes/include/apiClient.h>
#include <kubernetes/api/CoreV1API.h>
}
#include <kubernetes/config/kube_config.h>
```

For refernce:
[kubernetes/include/apiClient.h](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/c/blob/master/kubernetes/include/apiClient.h) and [kubernetes/api/CoreV1API.h](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/c/blob/master/kubernetes/api/CoreV1API.h) do not have it, but
[kubernetes/config/kube_config.h:7](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/c/blob/master/kubernetes/config/kube_config.h#L7) has `extern "C"`.

Comment: Seems like import order matters too right?. I got the same error if `extern "c"` block placed under the `kube_config.h` import. (Answer initially posted :) )

Comment: Yes, it matters, because [kubernetes/config/kube_config.h:4](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/c/blob/master/kubernetes/config/kube_config.h#L4) includes "../include/apiClient.h" w/o `extern "C"` and the second #include w/ `extern "C"` in your code is guarded.